# How can I create a Git bare repository from within Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-explorer

I'm using Visual Studio's Team Explorer and I'm able to connect to a Git bare repository that I've created through `git-bash.exe` on a Windows share on my server  via `git init --bare`.

I want to know if it's possible to create the bare repository using only Visual Studio, without having to use Git, since I'm able to do the basic stuff with VS alone.

I don't have admin permissions on this machine, so I'm looking for the lowest common denominator, i.e., to use:

1. VS only;
2. VS and some extension through "Tools->Extensions and Updates...";
3. VS and Git Portable;
4. VS, some extension and Git Portable.

Answer (score 1):

Using tools 'within' the VS install directory on command-line (power shell or cmd).   (VS 2017)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd\git.exe"  init --bare
```

Answer (score 0):

We simply use TFS as the git repository. Sounds like you want to create your own repo locally. However I think you'd get something from this quick "Using Git with Visual Studio" course

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/using-git-with-visual-studio-2013-jump-start-8306

I know I did. Pretty much the same thing works for 2015 as well. I hope that helps.